# how to select inner verts?

Tags: modeling, vertices

I solidify this coat but after doing so, i found dificulty in making seam and uv unwrapping it, so i needed to delete the inner part of this coat but i wanted to do it automatically instead of selecting the verts and etc... does anybody knows how to do it?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you make a seam at the edges of the pipe and then change to faces select and use 'L'  to select the inner part it you should be able to select up to the seam boundaries